# How to retrieve bits from number

Tags: java, bit, bit-shift

Sometimes I come across the below code. I believe it is used to represent values as bits and they can be combined into a single number and retrieved later.

The number 34 consists of `01000000` and `00000100` or `2` and `32`. How do I work this out in Java? Somehow I have to compare 2 to some variable to do `X` and 32 tot another variable to do `Y`.

The following is a example with some of my thoughts.

*from the DotA modding wiki.*

```
DOTA_ABILITY_BEHAVIOR_HIDDEN               = 1 << 0, //Can be owned by a unit but can't be cast and won't show up on the HUD.
DOTA_ABILITY_BEHAVIOR_PASSIVE              = 1 << 1, //Cannot be cast like above but this one shows up on the ability HUD.
DOTA_ABILITY_BEHAVIOR_NO_TARGET            = 1 << 2, //Doesn't need a target to be cast, ability fires off as soon as the button is pressed.
DOTA_ABILITY_BEHAVIOR_UNIT_TARGET          = 1 << 3, //Needs a target to be cast on.
DOTA_ABILITY_BEHAVIOR_POINT                = 1 << 4, //Can be cast anywhere the mouse cursor is (if a unit is clicked it will just be cast where the unit was standing).
DOTA_ABILITY_BEHAVIOR_AOE                  = 1 << 5, //Draws a radius where the ability will have effect. Kinda like POINT but with a an area of effect display.
//...
```

So these "behaviors" get stored as 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, etc. But the whole idea of this seems to be able to store multiple types into a single number/bytes and retrieve these later. I see usages like this:

```
DOTA_ABILITY_BEHAVIOR_AOE | DOTA_ABILITY_BEHAVIOR_PASSIVE
```

Which seems to be `34`. The only combination that would yield 34 would be this one `DOTA_ABILITY_BEHAVIOR_AOE | DOTA_ABILITY_BEHAVIOR_PASSIVE` and I believe that every combination made this way would be unique as long as you don't use the same value twice.

So how do I retrieve these two numbers from the number `34`? And are there any limitations in the usage like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those special numbers are called **bit masks**, used to **set and read out binary flags**.
 A `byte`, `short`, `int` or `long` value can thus hold multiple of those flags.

Example:

```
int flag1 = 0b0000001; // 1<<0, or 1
int flag2 = 0b0000010; // 1<<1, or 2
int flag3 = 0b0000100; // 1<<2, or 4
```

To combine flags:

```
int combined= flag1 | flag2;
```

To set a flag:

```
combined = combined | flag3;
```

To unset a flag:

```
combined = combined & ~flag;
```

To check if a flag is set:

```
boolean set3 = (combined & flag3) !=0;
```

Comment: Sidequestion: I get binary literals are not supported at this language level. Maybe it's related to `(34 & 2 == 2)` yields the error `operator & cannot be applied to int`

Comment: That's simply a problem with precedence: 34 & 2 == 2 means 34 & (2==2), which causes the compiler error that the bitwise-and (&) cannot be applied to int and boolean. Use parentheses ((34 & 2) == 2) and everything's fine.

Comment: Precedence of operators in Java: http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/

Answer (score 1):

```
int x = DOTA_ABILITY_BEHAVIOR_AOE | DOTA_ABILITY_BEHAVIOR_PASSIVE

if (x & DOTA_ABILITY_BEHAVIOR_AOE == DOTA_ABILITY_BEHAVIOR_AOE)
    // do stuff
```

You can add as many values represented by a single bit as the data type can store.

Comment: I knew the answer would be as simple as this but `(34 & 2 == 2)` yields the error `operator & cannot be applied to int`

Comment: `if ((x & DOTA_ABILITY_BEHAVIOR_AOE) == DOTA_ABILITY_BEHAVIOR_AOE)`

Comment: It should probably be uint

Answer (score 1):

About the part where you mentioned how to get back the bits used to obtain 34. I will post a 'solution' to give an idea about one way to achieve it. It is probably not the best way.

You have mentioned...

```
DOTA_ABILITY_BEHAVIOR_HIDDEN               = 1 << 0  # 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
DOTA_ABILITY_BEHAVIOR_PASSIVE              = 1 << 1  # 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
DOTA_ABILITY_BEHAVIOR_NO_TARGET            = 1 << 2  # 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
DOTA_ABILITY_BEHAVIOR_UNIT_TARGET          = 1 << 3  # 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
DOTA_ABILITY_BEHAVIOR_POINT                = 1 << 4  # 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
DOTA_ABILITY_BEHAVIOR_AOE                  = 1 << 5  # 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
```

And 34 in binary is `0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0`.

If we keep shifting left and check to see if the bit at the 0th index is set.

```
List<Integer> indx = new ArrayList<Integer>();
int count = 0;
while(n != 0) { 
    if(n & 0x1 == 1)
        indx.add(count);
    n = n >> 1;
    count++;
}
```

For 34, `indx` will contain `[1,5]`. You can use this to recreate which bits were used to form it `[DOTA_ABILITY_BEHAVIOR_PASSIVE, DOTA_ABILITY_BEHAVIOR_AOE]`.

Comment: This is indeed not the best way but it does give insight into what is going on. +1

Answer (score -1):

Since nobody has answered your specific question:

```
Decimal 34 == Hex 0022 == Binary 0000 0000 0010 0010
```

Your values are

```
DOTA_ABILITY_BEHAVIOR_HIDDEN       = 1 << 0, // 0000 0000 0000 0001
DOTA_ABILITY_BEHAVIOR_PASSIVE      = 1 << 1, // 0000 0000 0000 0010
DOTA_ABILITY_BEHAVIOR_NO_TARGET    = 1 << 2, // 0000 0000 0000 0100
DOTA_ABILITY_BEHAVIOR_UNIT_TARGET  = 1 << 3, // 0000 0000 0000 1000
DOTA_ABILITY_BEHAVIOR_POINT        = 1 << 4, // 0000 0000 0001 0000
DOTA_ABILITY_BEHAVIOR_AOE          = 1 << 5, // 0000 0000 0010 0000
```

The two values that can be OR'ed together to make decimal 34 are

```
DOTA_ABILITY_BEHAVIOR_PASSIVE | DOTA_ABILITY_BEHAVIOR_AOE
```